# How to find packages when updating Ubuntu and creating standard source.list file

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

I just upgrade to `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, amd64`.  I'm trying to install some software and it says for `Ubuntu 13.10` and above, the following libraries need to be installed for 32-bit compatibility components:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxtst6:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 \
libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 \
libncurses5:i386 libudev1:i386 libusb-1.0:i386 libusb-0.1:i386 \
gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

I know when I had `Ubuntu 13.10` I was able to download these packages, but now that I updated, none of these packages can be found:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgtk2.0-0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk2.0-0'
```

How do I go about finding these packages in `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, amd64`?  Why could I find them in 13.10 and they no longer exist in 14.04?  Did these things get renamed and moved around?  How do I find out and resolve this issue?  How do people resolve these issues when updating Ubuntu?  Thanks in advance.

### Edit

I get this error message when running commands suggested below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgtk2.0-0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk2.0-0'
E: Unable to locate package libxtst6
E: Unable to locate package libpangox-1.0-0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpangox-1.0-0'
E: Unable to locate package libpangoxft-1.0-0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpangoxft-1.0-0'
E: Unable to locate package libidn11
E: Unable to locate package libglu1-mesa
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5
E: Unable to locate package libudev1
E: Unable to locate package libusb-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libusb-1.0'
E: Unable to locate package libusb-0.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libusb-0.1'
E: Unable to locate package gtk2-engines-murrine
```

Comment: Well, the [package exists](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgtk2.0-0), have you run `sudo apt-get update`? Are your sources pointing to the main Ubuntu repos?

Comment: Yes I ran update/upgrade.  Everything is the latest.

Comment: Sorry, I got mesed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command automatically installs **`i386` packages**:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

If you want to remove `i386` libraries:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

Source: [Debian Multiarch HowTo](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)

If it still doesn't work, create a new `sources.list` from http://repogen.simplylinux.ch. This is what you'll need for a standard, clean `sources.list`:

[image]

[image]

Always backup the current file:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
```

Restore with:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.backup /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Ok so what procedure should I follow?  adding `i386` by `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then running the commands again, but no packages downloaded.

Comment: @user1527227 what software are you trying to install that requires i386 libs?

Comment: `LPCXpresso` for NXP microcontrollers.  http://www.lpcware.com/lpcxpresso/downloads/linux  .  I read the user manual for version 7(http://www.lpcware.com/system/files/LPCXpresso_User_Guide_1.pdf) in section 2.2.2 of page 8, it says to run the commands I listed up in the question stem.

Comment: @user1527227 This command works on my 14.04 x64: `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxtst6:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libncurses5:i386 libudev1:i386 libusb-1.0:i386 libusb-0.1:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386`. Try it!

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote.  Please see edit above for errors...  I ran these commands before for ubuntu 13.10 32-bit and it worked.  it just hasnt worked since i updated @Cornelius

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/apt/source.list` file in your answer please? @Cornelius