# Ubuntu LTS16.04 - packages libglib2.0:0:i386 and libkeyutils1:i386 missing

Tags: package-management

I'm very new to Ubuntu, and I'm trying to install a load generator onto this platform for performance testing.

Two of my per-requisites for this installation are missing:

dpkg-query: no packages found matching **libkeyutils1:i386**

dpkg-query: no packages found matching **libglib2.0-0:i386**

Unfortunately if I try to do an apt-install, they cannot be found either.  I've looked on https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libkeyutils1/download for example, but I cannot find packages with the :i386 following the name.  Am I missing something obvious here, or is there any other way i can grab these?

Many Thanks, Claire

Comment: I resolved part way by following instructions in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463457/how-to-find-packages-when-updating-ubuntu-and-creating-standard-source-list-file
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding the i386 architecture.
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libkeyutils1:i386

Hopefully this will of use to someone in the future.